# MDX Filter Unknown from list of states / provinces also removes provinces

Tags: filter, mdx

I am trying to exclude Unknown from a dimension [Ship To State] that contains Provinces and States.

The first expression throws out Provinces as well as States, and I don't know why -

this mdx lists only states (excludes Unknown, and for some reason, Provinces):

```
WITH 
MEMBER measures.ParameterCaption as [Ship To].[Ship To State].currentmember.member_caption

MEMBER measures.ParameterValue as [Ship To].[Ship To State].currentmember.uniquename
SELECT {measures.ParameterCaption, measures.ParameterValue}  ON COLUMNS,
FILTER([Ship To].[Ship To State].children,

[Ship To].[Ship To State].currentmember<>[Ship To].[Ship To State].&[Unknown]

) ON ROWS
FROM [Invoiced Orders]
```

this mdx lists states and provinces correctly, and excludes Unknown:

```
WITH 
MEMBER measures.ParameterCaption as [Ship To].[Ship To State].currentmember.member_caption
MEMBER measures.ParameterValue as [Ship To].[Ship To State].currentmember.uniquename
SELECT {measures.ParameterCaption, measures.ParameterValue}  ON COLUMNS,
FILTER([Ship To].[Ship To State].children,

measures.ParameterCaption <> "Unknown"

) ON ROWS
FROM [Invoiced Orders]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your comparison is a known member (or set of members), like your example, you could use the `Except()` function to directly remove it from the set.

```
Except(
    [Ship To].[Ship To State].children,
    {[Ship To].[Ship To State].&[Unknown]}
)
```

Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144900.aspx